# ZFS - grub zfs detection failed

Tags: grub2, zfs

I installed with my root pool as `rpool` before the installer had the option.

My main HDD bit the dust, so I'm now in the process of resilvering and in the meantime I am reinstalling grub on the new drive. Unfortunately I cannot get ZFS to be properly detected. I get the dreaded `error: unknown filesystem.` error from grub.

Note that I don't think it has anything to do with resilvering because I am probing an existing [not new] device.

You'll see that it passes all checks except #12 which seems to be the feature check. I don't see any feature error in the log however. I have all the 0.8.3 features enabled.

Can I force it to detect as ZFS, or is there a way to fix grub?

Logs below:

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# grub-probe --device /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2 -vvvvvvvvvv
grub-probe: info: cannot open `/boot/grub/device.map': No such file or directory.
grub-probe: info: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2 is not present.
grub-probe: info: Looking for /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sdb is a parent of /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2.
grub-probe: info: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2 starts from 1050624.
grub-probe: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hostdisk//dev/sdb'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sdb is 3907029168.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hostdisk//dev/sdb'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sdb is 3907029168.
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:417: opening the device `/dev/sdb' in open_device()
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:417: opening the device `/dev/sdb1' in open_device()
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb1'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb1'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:417: opening the device `/dev/sdb2' in open_device()
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x20494645; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hostdisk//dev/sdb'.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-probe: info: Partition 0 starts from 2048.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-probe: info: Partition 1 starts from 1050624.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hostdisk//dev/sdb'.
grub-probe: info: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2 is present.
grub-probe: info: Looking for /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sdb is a parent of /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2.
grub-probe: info: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2 starts from 1050624.
grub-probe: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hostdisk//dev/sdb'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sdb is 3907029168.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hostdisk//dev/sdb'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sdb is 3907029168.
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:417: opening the device `/dev/sdb' in open_device()
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x20494645; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hostdisk//dev/sdb'.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-probe: info: Partition 0 starts from 2048.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-probe: info: Partition 1 starts from 1050624.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hostdisk//dev/sdb'.
grub-probe: info: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2 is present.
grub-probe: info: Looking for /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sdb is a parent of /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2.
grub-probe: info: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1ER164_W4Z04ZJX-part2 starts from 1050624.
grub-probe: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hostdisk//dev/sdb'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sdb is 3907029168.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hostdisk//dev/sdb'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sdb is 3907029168.
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:417: opening the device `/dev/sdb' in open_device()
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:137: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sdb for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sdb.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x20494645; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hostdisk//dev/sdb'.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-probe: info: Partition 0 starts from 2048.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-probe: info: Partition 1 starts from 1050624.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hostdisk//dev/sdb'.
grub-probe: info: opening hostdisk//dev/sdb,gpt2.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hostdisk//dev/sdb,gpt2'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sdb is 3907029168.
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:90: Read a valid GPT header
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 0: start=2048, length=1048576
grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:114: GPT entry 1: start=1050624, length=3905978368
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting zfs...
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:417: opening the device `/dev/sdb2' in open_device()
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1196: label ok 0
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1011: check 2 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1022: check 3 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1029: check 4 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1039: check 6 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1047: check 7 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1058: check 8 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1068: check 9 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1090: check 11 passed
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1196: label ok 1
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1011: check 2 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1022: check 3 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1029: check 4 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1039: check 6 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1047: check 7 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1058: check 8 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1068: check 9 passed
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1090: check 11 passed
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1196: label ok 2
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1196: label ok 3
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: zfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting xfs...
grub-core/fs/xfs.c:909: Reading sb
grub-core/fs/xfs.c:258: Validating superblock
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: xfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ufs2...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ufs2 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ufs1_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ufs1_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ufs1...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ufs1 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting udf...
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:396: reusing open device `/dev/sdb2'
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: udf detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting tarfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: tarfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting squash4...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: squash4 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting sfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: sfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting romfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: romfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting reiserfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: reiserfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting procfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: procfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting odc...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: odc detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ntfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ntfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting nilfs2...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: nilfs2 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting newc...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: newc detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix3_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix3_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix3...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix3 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix2_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix2_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix2...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix2 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting jfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: jfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting iso9660...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: iso9660 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting hfsplus...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: hfsplus detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting hfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: hfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting fat...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: fat detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting f2fs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: f2fs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ext2...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ext2 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting exfat...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: exfat detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting cpiofs_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: cpiofs_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting cpiofs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: cpiofs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting cbfs...
grub-core/kern/disk.c:421: Read out of range: sector 0xe902808e (attempt to read or write outside of partition).
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: cbfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting btrfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: btrfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting bfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: bfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting afs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: afs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting affs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: affs detection failed.
grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just coming across your question while looking for some answers concerning ZFS myself, so I'm pretty steeped in the issue right now.

While I don't have a direct solution, I thought I might share some resources from a working system:

1. UUIDs are your friend - since `/dev/disk/by-id` is not particularly helpful for `/etc/fstab`, so make sure you're up on which one's which using `lsblk -f` and/or `blkid`:

```
$ lsblk -f

nvme0n1
│                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p1
│    vfat   FAT32       5363-5E6F                             485.1M     5% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2
│    swap   1           e5e9eace-5ce4-4bea-a900-e836788963e7                [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3
│    zfs_me 5000  bpool 11441242366189825385                                
└─nvme0n1p4
     zfs_me 5000  rpool 10749750096631427503 

$ blkid | grep nvme
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="5363-5E6F" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="09716541-5559-49f9-a998-e06bc57c1fe6"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="e5e9eace-5ce4-4bea-a900-e836788963e7" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="69e175df-272a-7e4e-8691-c27bc7f08b32"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="bpool" UUID="11441242366189825385" UUID_SUB="9297990641780606350" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="4716a6e3-b84f-344a-a8eb-528f4cbd0ff0"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="rpool" UUID="10749750096631427503" UUID_SUB="9348454491950206043" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="72c4025b-023f-ef43-878d-9e1f60af796b"

$ cat /etc/fstab   # auto-generated during installer setup
❯ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation

UUID=5363-5E6F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
/boot/efi/grub  /boot/grub  none    defaults,bind   0   0
UUID=e5e9eace-5ce4-4bea-a900-e836788963e7   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

2. Make sure your grub-related packages are all present in your installation. From 21.10 installer-generated setup:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep grub
grub-common/impish,now 2.04-1ubuntu47 amd64 [installed,automatic]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/impish,now 2.04-1ubuntu47 amd64 [installed,automatic]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/impish,now 1.173+2.04-1ubuntu47 amd64 [installed,automatic]
grub-efi-amd64/impish,now 2.04-1ubuntu47 amd64 [installed]
grub2-common/impish,now 2.04-1ubuntu47 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

3. If the ZFS-specific file(s) in `/etc/grub.d` are not present, obtain a copy of it/them and place them in the folder:

```
❯ ls -la /etc/grub.d
total 117
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    13 Jan 27 14:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 188 root root   311 Jan 27 15:21 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10627 Sep  2 05:37 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6258 Sep  2 05:37 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 18151 Sep  2 05:37 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 43031 Sep  2 05:37 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12894 Sep  2 05:37 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1992 Oct  7 03:20 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12059 Sep  2 05:37 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1424 Sep  2 05:37 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   214 Sep  2 05:37 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   216 Sep  2 05:37 41_custom
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 Sep  2 05:37 README
```

Note: I tried to attach `10_linux_zfs` but it was too long. I found the source code for the proper package, though - on the right side you can download it in `.tar.gz` format and extract the `10_linux_zfs` file, or download the `grub-common-2.04-1ubuntu47.deb` file and re-install the entire thing:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/grub-common

(notice if you're using a different version, you can select between them at the top)

If re-installing from a local package, apt needs you to specify the file location - the `./` part at the start of the name.  Relative is OK, but it needs to be explicit:

```
$ sudo apt install -y --reinstall ./grub-common-2.04-1ubuntu47.deb
```

Apt should resolve any other dependencies you might need, so I prefer installing individual `.deb`s through `apt` rather than `dpkg -i`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Your information allowed me to validate everything in my installation was right. I ran a package upgrade and re-downloaded `10_linux_zfs` and that fixed it. There were minor updates in `10_linux_zfs` from what I had to the latest version. Whatever it was, doing a full upgrade fixed it. My server has been down since July so I am very grateful for your help!

Comment: oh my gosh, that's so great! I'm so happy I could help!  Thanks for letting me know :) And congratulations on your server running again! That's awesome!